# Erlang frames - dictionary datatype

Tags: erlang, runtime

I ran into some texts about the introduction of a "frame" datatype into Erlang, basically a dictionary(associative array) type thats common in other languages... one that would be preserved at runtime (unlike records)... 
any ideas about where this innitiative is at? will it be implemented in R13? R14? 
would be very usefull... I used "dict" quite often, however a built in datatype thats more lightweight would be much cooler

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know no one from Erlang/OTP team stated official position on this proposal. Moreover there is still no [formal EEP](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0000.html) on the subject. Though a lot of developers support this proposal, but compromise on syntax and some semantics is still to be reached. For more information see [erlang-questions mailing list archive](http://www.nabble.com/forum/Search.jtp?query=frames+records&local=y&forum=14096).

Comment: thanks...
its a shame that this and other minor things dont get handled (native strings), as they would significantly increase adoption and liveliness of the community

Comment: An UTF-8 implementation is in the pipeline and could be considered as a native string implementation.